# To explicitly write formula for distance function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$d_A (x) = \inf \{ |x-a| | a \in A \}$

$A = \mathbb{Z}$

Now i know $d_A = 0$ , when $x = k , k \in \mathbb{Z}$

But how to go about when it lies between two integers ?

Comment: Hint: You can find a formula in terms of the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$